# ngx-monaco-editor - unable to set layout size when container changes (using tab panel)

Tags: angular, primeng, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

I am struggling with an instance of an `ngx-monaco-editor` inside a primeng tab panel which seems to **loses its size calculations** when switching to another tab, changing the model value bound to the editor and then switching back to the initial tab again.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng9-tabs-monaco-editor

Steps to replicate using URL above:

- The 'Editor' tab will be initially selected
- Select 'Tab 2'
- Click the 'change code' button
- Change back to the 'Editor' tab and now see that the editor has shrunk in size

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Inspecting in the Dom, the originally assigned style is still present.

As you can see from the source code in my sample app, I also tried using the editor's `layout` method in the tab change event to attempt to force a recalculation of the size based on the container but this has made no difference

Interestingly if I resize the window this does seem to trigger the editor component to resize again correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure what the root cause is but using `*ngIf` on the editor container fixes the problem. Please take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng9-tabs-monaco-editor-vjxnck?file=src/app/app.component.html) -

```js
handleTabChange(tabChangeEvent: { originalEvent: Event; index: number }) {
    if (tabChangeEvent.index === 0) {
      //this.monacoEditor.editor.layout();
      this.showEditor = true;
    } else {
      this.showEditor = false;
    }
  }
```

Then in your template -

```
<div style="height: 500px" *ngIf="showEditor">
            <ngx-monaco-editor #monacoEditor style="height:100%;" [options]="editorOptions" [(ngModel)]="code">
            </ngx-monaco-editor>
        </div>
```

Comment: How do you even debug this? I literally spent hours on this exact problem, but using *ngIf really solved it.

Comment: *ngIf is forcing the component to reload himself -> destroy and reinit. This is the reason why this is working

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that the issue is not related to angular component. *This is all about [Monaco editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/)*.

#### How Monaco finds its actual layout?

Consider a page with a visible Monaco editor inside a container. When Monaco editor is loaded, it sets the layout size according to visible view. **So what happens if you request an update on Monaco when is inside a hidden container?** Obviously, there's no visible view for Monaco to set its layout props. The editor sets layout according to hidden view! *This is why you see a dot instead of area.* Now when this view comes to visible state, the editor doesn't update the layout even by calling `.layout()` method or setting `automaticLayout: true` in `options`. You may trigger by *resizing the browser*, *updating editor again* or some *Angular tricks*.

Now you understand how it works. So *please avoid updating Monaco when is inside an invisible view*. Let this to be done after containing view become visible.

Answer (score 2):

Using `*ngIf` will initialize / destroy the `ngx-monaco-editor` component, which may or may not be helpful.

When I have a component containing a `ngx-monaco-editor`, I  create the following function that I call whenever I need to resize the monaco editor.

```
    resizeComponents() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        }, 200);
    }
```

### EXAMPLE OF USE:

#### View

```
<div (click)="onTabChange('myTab')">Change Tab</div>
```

#### Component

```
onTabChange(myTab) {
   
    // execute tab change logic
    this.resizeComponents()
}
```

Again, this is an alternative approach in case you don't want to re-initialize the editor.